# How to show PhotoViewGallery class index value in appBar

Tags: flutter

I'm using photo_view_gallery class and I would like to show dynamically the value of current image *index* of PhotoViewGallery.builder into the appBar.

I'm new in Flutter, I googled a lot but I can't found any solution for this

```
body: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
        itemCount: listaPagine.length,
        builder: (context, index) {
          saveIndex(index);
          String myImg =
              'http://www.attilofficina.altervista.org/phpbackend/JOB/000004/fullsize/' +
                  listaPagine[index].nomefile.toString() +
                  '.jpg';
          return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
            imageProvider: AdvancedNetworkImage(myImg,
                retryLimit: 1, timeoutDuration: Duration(seconds: 30)),
          );
        },
      ),
```

I also try a function that save index to another variable, but the value is still unavailable in appBar

Here the code and position of this function (in appBar is shown null)

```
class GalleryPageState extends State<GalleryPage> {
int curr;
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  saveIndex(int index) {
      int curr = index;
      print('*** curr = ' + curr.toString()); /// PRINTS CORRECT VALUE
      return curr;
    }
  ...
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(curr.toString(),  /// BUT IT SHOWS NULL
        ),
  ),      
  body: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
        itemCount: listaPagine.length,
        builder: (context, index) {
          salvaIndex(index);
          String myImg =
              'http://www.attilofficina.altervista.org/phpbackend/JOB/000004/fullsize/' +
                  listaPagine[index].nomefile.toString() +
                  '.jpg';
          return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
            imageProvider: AdvancedNetworkImage(myImg,
                retryLimit: 1, timeoutDuration: Duration(seconds: 30)),
          );
        },
      ),
   ); 
  }
}
```

Can someone help me?
special thanks mario

Comment: can you share the code where you saving the index?

Comment: sure, I've added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `onPageChanged`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view_gallery.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<String> listaPagine = [
    'https://picsum.photos/id/451/200/300',
    'https://picsum.photos/id/200/200/300'
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('# $_currentIndex'),
      ),
      body: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
        itemCount: listaPagine.length,
        builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          String myImg = listaPagine[index];

          return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
            imageProvider: NetworkImage(myImg),
          );
        },
        onPageChanged: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks in januw for immediate response.
Your solution is great and works perfectly !!!
Now I need a little more time to fully understand your code

Answer (score 1):

There's three things wrong in your following code:

```
 saveIndex(int index) {
      int curr = index;
      print('*** curr = ' + curr.toString()); /// PRINTS CORRECT VALUE
      return curr;
    }
```

1. Here you are creating new `int curr` variable which should be `curr` to use the existing global scope variable.
2. You should create the `saveIndex` method outside of `build` function.
3. Also you should update the variable in `setState` like

```
setState((){
  curr=index;
});
```

This will update the variable and recreate the widget tree with `AppBar` with updated values.

Also you don't need the return statement in `saveIndex`

**Editing for @attila's help**

The basic about the state is, it just keep the current state or values in memory. You can always change any value & it will be updated in the state but it will not reflected on the UI. Because your application or view still don't know that some value is updated & it needs to re-render the UI.

That's where the `setState` come in picture. What it does is while updating the value it also call the build function so new UI with updated values could be re-rendered on screen.

To test it, you can just update the values & call `setState((){});` after that. It will still work as same.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you Aakash Kumar for reply.
I followed your instructions to resolve the 3 errors of my code!
But really I didn't understand exactly how and where to implement setState, so also with the help of the januw code I realized that it had to be inserted in:
onPageChanged: (index int) {
setState (() {
curr = index;
});
},
So your solution now works perfectly in my crude code!!!
Now I still need a little more time to fully understand your suggestions
But now I'm a happy man!
Even though I'm 57, I've lost my job and, not to go crazy, I'm learning Flutter!
Thank you, good luck!

Comment: Your welcome attila :)
I tried to explain some basics about `setState` may be it could help you. If not let me know. Best of luck..